# Android Google Maps Android V2 Check Entered location is in Ahmedabad

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dictionary, android-maps

I'm working with Google map v2, my issue is :

when user enter location at that time, i want to check that location in Ahmadabad or not.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Nirmal:On the first step you need to fetch the latitude and longitude.Then pass the coordinates on the following method.Then compare the value of city with Ahmadabad.

> ```
> public void getAddress(double lat, double lng) {
> Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(HomeActivity.mContext, Locale.getDefault());
> try {
>     List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
>     Address obj = addresses.get(0);
>     String add = obj.getAddressLine(0);
>     GUIStatics.currentAddress = obj.getSubAdminArea() + ","
>             + obj.getAdminArea();
>     GUIStatics.latitude = obj.getLatitude();
>     GUIStatics.longitude = obj.getLongitude();
>     GUIStatics.currentCity= obj.getSubAdminArea();
>     GUIStatics.currentState= obj.getAdminArea();
>     add = add + "\n" + obj.getCountryName();
>     add = add + "\n" + obj.getCountryCode();
>     add = add + "\n" + obj.getAdminArea();
>     add = add + "\n" + obj.getPostalCode();
>     add = add + "\n" + obj.getSubAdminArea();
>     add = add + "\n" + obj.getLocality();
>     add = add + "\n" + obj.getSubThoroughfare();
>
>     Log.v("IGA", "Address" + add);
>     // Toast.makeText(this, "Address=>" + add,
>     // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>
>     // TennisAppActivity.showDialog(add);
> } catch (IOException e) {
>     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
>     e.printStackTrace();
>     Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
> } }
> ```